# How to change permalink format for future articles, but keep previous permalinks the same in WordPress

Tags: links, wordpress

When I first started my website and didn't really know what I was doing so I made the permalink include the date in the permalink. This is problematic because if I were to change it to the simple website domain name and article name for the rest of them, it would change the old ones as well. If it changed the old ones it would have to be re-indexed onto google and all the backlinking from other places and interlinking would be broken.

I thought to change it and redirect the links with dates to the new permalink format, but I have tons of articles, and doing it manually would take forever.

Is there any way to make the future posts on WordPress use a different permalink format while keeping all the old posts having the same link?

Or is there a way to make all of the links on the website change to different permalink format without completely breaking indexing, backlinking, and interlinking structure?

[image]

To clarify I now have Month and name and am trying to change it to Plain.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the many redirect plugins available in the WordPress repository.

Please make a search using https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/redirect/

Just to mention a couple of them:

- [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)

> Redirection is the most popular redirect manager for WordPress. With
> it you can easily manage 301 redirections, keep track of 404 errors,
> and generally tidy up any loose ends your site may have. This can help
> reduce errors and improve your site ranking.
>
> Redirection is designed to be used on sites with a few redirects to
> sites with thousands of redirects.
>
> It has been a WordPress plugin for over 10 years and has been
> recommended countless times. And it’s free!

- [WP 404 Auto Redirect to Similar Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-404-auto-redirect-to-similar-post/)

> This plugin automatically redirect 404 pages to similar posts based on
> Title, Post Types & Taxonomies. If nothing similar is found, visitors
> will be redirected to the homepage or a custom URL.

- [404 to 301 – Redirect, Log and Notify 404 Errors](https://wordpress.org/plugins/404-to-301/)

> If you care about your website, you should take steps to avoid 404
> errors as it affects your SEO badly. 404 ( Page not found ) errors are
> common and we all hate it, even Search engines do the same! Install
> this plugin then sit back and relax. It will take care of 404 errors!

- [301 Redirects – Easy Redirect Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/eps-301-redirects/)

> 301 Redirects helps you manage and create 301 & 302 redirects for your WordPress site to improve SEO and visitor experience. With a user-friendly interface, 301 Redirects is easy to install and configure. Perfect for new sites or repairing links after re-organizing your existing WordPress content, or when your site has content that expires and you wish to avoid sending visitors to a 404 page.

---

**Their individual features vary.

Try and choose/use the one that best meets your needs.**

Comment: Do you know of any way on those plugins to changes all of the links (posts) to a different format / redirect all posts to the new permalink format? I would need to manually redirect like 120 pages to different URLs that way.

Comment: As mentioned, *"Their individual features vary.
Try and choose/use the one that best meets your needs."*. NO NEED to *"manually redirect like 120 pages"*.  `WP 404 Auto Redirect to Similar Post` or `Redirection` are your best bets.

Comment: Please remember to also accept the answer :)

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to redirect all the permalinks at once to a different one for each article for any of those WordPress plugins so I just entered in 115 redirects manually. Only took 30 minutes, but I'm going to expect the answer anyways :D